# xcode 4.3.2 and boost.framework cause CPU usage to >100%

Tags: boost, xcode4, frameworks, cpu-usage, code-completion

I'm facing a problem. Since I added boost to my project is the CPU usage always at maximum. Its a core i7 and 8GB RAM. Code completion and the other indexing stuff doesn't work. The only think that helps is restart Xcode. But after very shot time is the CPU again at max and the fan stats like a tornado.

I made the boost framework "boost.framework" by following this instructions:
http://www.danielsefton.com/2012/03/building-boost-1-49-with-clang-ios-5-1-and-xcode-4-3/

I appreciate every suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar (if not the very same) issue with my MacBookPro (max. CPU usage, tornado-like fan). In my case it turned out that the temp-sensor did not work properly.